# Android: send an onClick bash command to /dev/null

Tags: android, string, bash, onclick, dev-null

I made some buttons in my app that exec a bash cmd.

Here is my string:

```
    final String[] test = {"su","-c","echo test > /system/test.txt"};
```

This cmd works, in fact, i can see the test.txt file on /system/ with the line test inside.

My question is: When i push on the button for exec that cmd the device create a toast with the string "echo test /system/text.txt".
I'm guessing this is due to "-c", anyway:

```
    final String[] test = {"su","echo test > /system/test.txt"};
```

won't work, and:

```
    final String[] test = {"su","-c","echo test > /system/test.txt >> /dev/null"};
```

won't work as well and create a toast showing "echo test /system/test.txt /dev/null"

is there any way i can avoid this "problem"?

Also, can anyone show me a little function that create a toast with a spinning wheel when i onClick to the button that exec it?

Thanks!!!

Comment: This is probably a side effect of the su hack on your particular phone, intended to give the user the vaguest idea of how apps are using it.  And incidentally, you are executing a shell command, but that shell is probably not bash, but rather toolbox or possibly busybox.

Comment: To clarify, /dev/null is not the answer, as neither stdout nor stderr is involved in the creation of the Toast.  It is very intentional that this user security notification *not* be something which can be hidden.

Answer (score -1):

This extract from `su` manual should clear your question about `-c` option:

`-c, --command=COMMAND
              pass a single COMMAND to the shell with -c`

And

```
final String[] test = {"su","-c","echo test > /system/test.txt >> /dev/null"};
```

won't work because Android don't have `/dev/null` device. To get it work you need to have a `-c` option after `su` and get a rid of `/dev/null`. You may use android API to delete this file instead.

Comment: Hello, the command itself works well! i don't need to delete the file! i need to remove the toast that appears when i click on the button that exec the command!!!

Comment: I don't get it. Why did you created this toast if you don't wanna display your results there?

Comment: the "toast" appear itself whwnever you execute a bash "su -c cmd" command: an example is when you execute an app with root permission already granted... once you open it and it exec "su" a toast message appear saying "this app has now root access" ... in my case appear

"this app as now root access 

echo test > etc "

Comment: Untrue, android does have a /dev/null

Comment: @Chris Stratton - You're wrong the Android OS do have the `/dev/null` device but you have to have a rooted device to see it. Without root permissions you can't go lower than `/storage` (down to `/`).

Comment: Ah, no, that would *not* be true.  Only specific areas are restricted, and they vary by version.  /dev/null is also utterly unrelated to the question asked, since the Toast has nothing to do with stdout or stderr.